# Updating Custom Posts via CSV Import

Tags: csv

I'm writing a plugin so i can regularly upload CSV files to update data in post metas. The problem is that the order of the columns sometimes change with each CSV file i am supplied with. The code i have matches the columns using the number of the column:

$name = trim($csvData[3]);

is there a way to locate the columns by the name of the column instead? (first row of csv) like:

$name = trim($csvData[first_name]);

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Add your CSV import code to the question so we can answer your question specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    class CsvReader{
      var $fields;            /** columns names retrieved after parsing */
        var $separator = ';';    /** separator used to explode each line */
        var $enclosure = '"';    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */
    
        var $max_row_size = 4096;    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */
    
        function parse_file($p_Filepath) {
    
            $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
            $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
            $keys_values = explode(',',$this->fields[0]);
    
            $content    =   array();
            $keys   =   $this->escape_string($keys_values);
    
            $i  =   1;
            while( ($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) {
                if( $row != null ) { // skip empty lines
                    $values =   explode(',',$row[0]);
                    if(count($keys) == count($values)){
                        $arr    =   array();
                        $new_values =   array();
                        $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                        for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++){
                            if($keys[$j] != ""){
                                $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                            }
                        }
    
                        $content[$i]=   $arr;
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($file);
            return $content;
        }
    
        function escape_string($data){
            $result =   array();
            foreach($data as $row){
                $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '',$row);
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }

/*Declaration*/

$csv= new CsvReader();
$csvData=$csv->parse_file($uploaded_csv_path);
print_r($csvData);
    ?>
```

Comment: Use above class for CSV reader